# NodeJS - using Q to do async operations on an array of objects, with a twist

Tags: arrays, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I'm also new to Q and promises, and have been struggling with this issue for days. I'm trying to iterate through a variable-length array of RECORDS, using an ID from each record in an async call to retrieve an OBJECT (in the case from redis).

The twist is that I need to combine some data from the RECORD with some data from the retrieved OBJECT, creating a new array from these combined objects which is then returned.

My failing code looks like this:

```
arrayOfThingRecords = [... an array of small objects, each with a 'thingid'...];
arrayOfCombinedObjects = [];

arrayOfThingRecords.forEach(function(thingRecord) {

    Q.ninvoke(redisClient, "HGETALL", thingRecord.thingid)
    .then((function (thingObject) {
        combinedThingObject = {
            thingStuffFromRecord: thingRecord.thingStuffFromRecord,
            thingStuffFromObject: thingObject.thingStuffFromObject
        };
    }).done(function () {
        arrayOfCombinedObjects.push(combinedThingObject)
    }); //   

}; // Then do stuff with arrayOfThingObjects...
```

I know that using the `forEach` is wrong, because it executes before the promises return. I've been trying to work with `Q.all()` and `Q.settled()`, and with building an array of promises, etc, but I'm completely confused and suspect/hope that I may be making this harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a global `arrayOfCombinedObjects = []` that you manually fill. Always resolve your promises with the result values of the respective operation. For example,

```
Q.ninvoke(redisClient, "HGETALL", thingRecord.thingid)
.then(function(thingObject) {
    return {
//  ^^^^^^
        thingStuffFromRecord: thingRecord.thingStuffFromRecord,
        thingStuffFromObject: thingObject.thingStuffFromObject
    };
});
```

becomes a promise *for* that object.

Now, using `Q.all` is the correct approach. It takes an *array of promises*, and combines them to a promise for an array of all the results. So we need to build an array of promises - an array of the promises for these objects from above. You can use the `forEach` iteration and `push` to put the array together, but using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is much easier. It then becomes

```
var arrayOfThingRecords = [... an array of small objects, each with a 'thingid'...];
var arrayOfPromises = arrayOfThingRecords.map(function(thingRecord) {
    return Q.ninvoke(redisClient, "HGETALL", thingRecord.thingid)
//  ^^^^^^ let the promise be part of the new array
    .then(function(thingObject) {
        return {
            thingStuffFromRecord: thingRecord.thingStuffFromRecord,
            thingStuffFromObject: thingObject.thingStuffFromObject
        };
    });
});
Q.all(arrayOfPromises).then(function(arrayOfCombinedObjects) {
    // Then do stuff with arrayOfThingObjects...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes total sense. I went back to 'doom pyramids' to get moving, but will swap that out with this approach soon. For some reason I find this promise stuff to be weirdly head-bending. Thanks again!